# Tacking methods onto `end`

Tags: ruby

At the end of this here block,

```
entries.map do |key_val|
  "[#{key_val.first}] \"#{key_val.last}\""
end.sort.join("\n")
```

I see `sort` tacked onto `end`. Is this common? What is it doing? I've never seen `end` being treated as the value of `return`. Is that what's happening? The `map` inside the method returns an array and you can grab onto it with `end`?

Comment: There's no "map within the method", map *is* the method.

Comment: What is "here blocK"? I know here doc, but not here block.

Comment: @sawa - "this here block" = "this block", with the nearness of the block colloquially emphasized.

Comment: It is absolutely colloquial.  I know, because I live in a region where it's commonly heard.  It's nonstandard, but that's not the same as "ungrammatical". See [this here dictionary entry](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/this+here).

Comment: @MarkReed Thanks for the link. My previous comment removed.

Comment: It's southern US, or western US language - as heard in cowboy movies. It is not standard english. It's usually used for humorous effect.

Comment: <<BLOCK Sort of like, "deep-fried, fried chicken"\nBLOCK (It's late.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't be fooled by the syntax. The block defined by `do`...`end` is just a special type of argument passed to the `map` call.  It doesn't go in parentheses or otherwise look like it's an argument, but it is one; the syntax of the method call runs all the way to the `end`.  So when you stick a `.`*method* on the `end`, you're calling that method on the return value of the `map` call - which is, hopefully, an Array.

There are various ways to rewrite so that it's clearer to those less familiar with Ruby's syntax oddities.  For instance, add some parentheses to make the precedence explicit, as suggested by @AndrewMarshall:

```
(entries.map do |key_val|
  "[#{key_val.first}] \"#{key_val.last}\""
end).sort.join("\n")
```

Or create a Proc out of the block and pass it inside the method call parentheses using `&`, so the chained method call is in a more familiar place syntactically (in this one I also rewrote the block itself in what I think is a cleaner style):

```
block = proc do |key, val|
  %([#{key}] "#{val}")
end

entries.map(&block).sort.join("\n")
```

You can combine that with removing a level of chaining, as in AJcodez's answer:

```
intermediate_array = entries.map(&block)
intermediate_array.sort.join("\n")
```

Or eliminate the chaining entirely:

```
mapped = entries.map(&block)
sorted = mapped.sort
joined = sorted.join("\n")
return joined
```

Basically, the fact that the method call syntax is attached to the `end` is just a quirk of Ruby's block-passing syntax (and, of course, also works if you attach the method call to the closing brace of a `{`...`}` block). You're just calling a method (that happens to take a block, which you supply) and then calling a second method on the return value of the first.

Comment: It's all clear now. Just weird syntax which I'm glad to recognize now. Thanks all!

Comment: Glad it's clear, hope I helped some, anyway. You may want to look at how I modified your block above - you can let Ruby split the pair for you by naming two parameters, and use the `%X...X` syntax to avoid having to escape the embedded double quotes.

Comment: You should have just said that the block is part of the construction for method evaluation. It is inappropriate to say that a block is an argument. They are pretty much different. Arguments are evaluated prior to the evaluation of the method that takes them; blocks are not. The timing of block evaluation is controlled by the method that takes it.

Comment: Proc can be an argument. Block is not even an object. Proc and block are different.

Comment: Yes, they're different, but as long as I had some way of constructing a Proc (which you can't currently do without a block, admittedly), I could do everything else that blocks do by just passing Procs around.  A block is effectively, if not syntactically, an argument: an extra piece of information that is supplied to the method, that the method is free to use as it sees fit.  That's all I meant.

Comment: ya better explanation :) "You cannot delete the accepted answer" oh well

Comment: Also possibly useful in showing what’s happening is adding parenthesis in the right (equivalent) way while keeping everything else the same: `(entries.map do |e| ... end).sort`.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby everything returns a value, including blocks. Same as:

```
intermediate_array = entries.map do |key_val|
  "[#{key_val.first}] \"#{key_val.last}\""
end
intermediate_array.sort.join("\n")
```

I prefer the above syntax choice, but both are perfectly valid for the interpreter.

Comment: Blocks return values, but the invocant of the `sort` here is not the return value of the block. The fact that the method call syntax is attached to the `end` is misleading - it's not the block's return value, but `map`'s.

Comment: This answer is misleading as @MarkReed says—[his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19531461/211563) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe calling a method on 'end' is common practice. I have been learning ruby for about 2 months now, and have not once come across that syntax.

Comment: http://testfirst.org/learn_ruby - they're used here. And now you know what they mean!

Comment: It is common practice. (Been doing Ruby for four years and have seen it a lot.)